# How do you give a user a role by role ID in Discord.JS V13 (latest)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a verification bot for my new Discord server, but I need to know how to assign roles in Discord.JS 13 latest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this something like same thing with getting `member.id`.

```
const member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])
```

You can create the code similar to this.

```
const role = message.mentions.roles.first() || message.guild.roles.cache.get(args[0])
```

Now you can adjust your code file:

```
const member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])
const role = message.mentions.roles.first() || message.guild.roles.cache.get(args[1])

member.roles.add(role) //To add the mentioned or given role id the the member.
```

You can see the image below, the format is `args[0]` for `member` and `args[1]` is for `role`. Try to experiment your code for this time!

[image: Example add role]

Answer (score 1):

It's `GuildMember.roles.add(roleOrRoles, [optionalReason])`. In the discord.js docs: [docs: -addrole](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add).